# Mule Database procedure/Function syntax to read Oracle Struct Object

Tags: database, oracle, mule

I have use as below .

A mule flow which contains the database as outbound endpoint with procedure call syntax.

```
CALL PROC_NAME(#['dd';string;IN],#[result;resultSet;OUT]);
```

But the procedure will return a oracle struct type object. When I am trying to execute mule flow I am facing issues.

Any one came across this type of scenario.

Comment: Show the exceptions you are facing. Specify what Mule version you are using.

Comment: Hi David, this is the  procedure i am using   create or replace procedure emp_proc(test In String,emp OUT emp_struct)
as 
begin
SELECT * into emp FROM emp_struct_table;
end;   Mule runtime is :cloudhub december 2013 and Mule studio version is 3.5

Comment: Root Exception stack trace:
[Error: unresolvable property or identifier: result]
[Near : {... result,resultSet,OUT ....}]

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding bits of info in comments: post the full stack, also the Mule config and, again, please specify the version you're using.